# file exist with special folder not working on windows seven

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-server-2008, filepath, windows

i set the string variable from path + file name  with Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder and that's file haven't any extension
that is work correctly on windows server 2003 and xp but not working on windows 7 and windows server 2008

```
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "testxyz");

if (File.Exists(path))            
{return true;}
else
{return false;}
```

Comment: are you sure your file is in system32 folder and not in system?

Answer (score 2):

please, check two things:

- is application have rights to system directory?
- is file at this folder really exists?

working example (win7 32 bit):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace testPath
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "main.cpl");
            Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(path));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i was check the full path of file with break point and open with run menu  , and set compatibility  with run as administrator but dosnt work on windows 7 and server 2008

Answer (score 0):

windows 7 or 2008 server x64 platform has two folder system32 and systemWOW32  special folder class in .net return systemWOW64 as system32 and when we use  specialfolder.system . return systemWOW64.

Answer (score 0):

If your process does not have rights, `File.Exists` will return false and not throw an exception.

Try open or enumerate the files in the local directory to see if you get an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.